# How to create an input table (6 records) with merged heading in an Access Form using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

What's the best control that supports multi input records with columns and rows heading merging? Or is using dynamic creation of labels and textboxes better?

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

or like this with merged heading:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would not be impossible to create a form in VBA, it is not recommended. Furthermore, numbered field names in a table in a relational database are nearly always a sign of bad design. Therefore, you should not need merged headings. That being said, you can use a continuous form.

[image: merged headings]

However, instead of trying to replicate an Excel set-up in MS Access, I suggest you read about database design, for example: http://r937.com/relational.html

Get the database design right and then worry about headings.

Comment: thanks Remou, yes It's much better not to create the form in vba but I needed the merging to avoid creating multi forms. will be back later to get support of final design.thanks alot.